# JIRA: how to find users who closed items without item having been tested

Tags: jira, jql, software-quality

In Jira, I note that some items are getting set to 'Closed' by users without having passed through 'In Testing'

How can I find out who is doing this with a JQL query?

```
status was not in ("In Testing") and status in ("Ready For Production",Closed,Duplicate) and status changed by user
```

This is no good as it will pick up ANY changes made by 'user'
I want to know where 'user' specifically changed to 'closed' by said user

Answer (score 0):

Use `status was closed BY user`:

```
status was not in ("In Testing") and status in ("Ready For Production",Closed,Duplicate) and status was closed BY user
```